# How to find radius?

Tags: geometry, circles, spherical-geometry

When I am given centre of circle and a tangent of the circle. How can I get radius? I know radius is perpendicular to tangent so I applied distance foormula but what I got is ^2 of actual answer

Comment: you must construct the perpendicular to the Tangent line

Comment: I did that. But as I said my answer is ^2 of actual answer

Comment: then you have $r^2$

Comment: I propose to close this question because you have asked a very similar question an hour ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2438409)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will be the radius?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438409/what-will-be-the-radius)

Answer (score 1):

find the length of perpendicular from centre of the circle to the tangent.

if the equation of tangent is $ax+by+c$,  the radius is, 
$$ r = \left|\frac{ax_c+by_c+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right|$$

where, $x_c$ and $y_c$ are coordinates of center.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the line $ax+by + c = 0$

and a point not on the line $(x_1,y_1)$

The distance of a point from the line: $\frac {|ax_1 + by_1 + c|}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Distance between point $(x_0, y_0)$ and line $ax + by+ c=0$ is
$\qquad\frac {|ax_0 + by_0 + c|}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}= radius$
Your most probable mistake might be that you took $radius = r^2$ from equation of circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

Comment: I also did the same like you. But the actual answer is sqroot of my answer. so I think that we have to take r²

Comment: What's the question exactly?